# Estoy intentando darle una posicion especifica a un boton en Javafx, pero no esta funcionando, donde esta mi error?

Tags: java, javafx

Buenos dias estimados, estoy aprendiendo sobre GUIs en JAVAfx, despues de dar una buena buscada en google y dentro de este site, aun no consigo hacer que mi boton este donde yo necesito que este, estoy usando el *button.setLayoutX();* y el respectivo para Y, sin embargo el boton sigue apareciendo en todo el centro de la pantalla... aqui les presento mi codigo.

```
package mainbar;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Mainbar extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Image funcicon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("empleados.png"));
    Button funcbtn = new Button();
    funcbtn.setGraphic(new ImageView(funcicon));

    funcbtn.setText("");
    funcbtn.setPrefSize(65, 65);
    funcbtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    funcbtn.setLayoutX(250);
    funcbtn.setLayoutY(250);
    root.getChildren().add(funcbtn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 450);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi, debia substituir el *stackpane* por *pane* normal, el codigo quedo asi;

```
Pane root = new Pane();
    funcbtn.setLayoutX(250);
    funcbtn.setLayoutY(250);
    root.getChildren().add(funcbtn);
    clibtn.setLayoutX(350);
    clibtn.setLayoutY(350);
    root.getChildren().add(clibtn);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 450);
```